# Hide Flow buttons in salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, jquery, visual-workflow, css

Is it possible to hide the buttons in the flow? I know we have the option to hide previous. But I need to hide all the buttons as the flow is designed to share some information which I put on the lightning page and hence we don't need any button in that flow.

In the lightning page, I tried to use Jquery to hide the button using hide, remove method but no luck yet. If i run the query in browser the button disappears but not in the lightning component

[image]

Ex: $( ".slds-button--brand" ).remove(); it worked in browser but not through lightning component. I need to hide the finish button from here as per the screenshot

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can wait for a few weeks this should be possible in spring 18, with the hide footer option

See : http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_hide_screen_header_footer.htm?edition=&impact=

> To remove the header and footer, deselect Show Header and Show Footer when you configure a flow screen. If you remove the footer, the screen’s navigation buttons don’t appear.

Comment: thanks really nice, Yes I can wait for it. But one thing I observed when i put the flow in lightning page the content gets shrinked and the button appears at the right end. (The layout is one column so ideally it should take the entire screen) not sure if this is bug or this is how it is  . The attached screenshot has the issue

Comment: Meanwhile I had used the delay method and then using JS i am removing the button. Earlier it didn work because the page doesn loads fully and my hide command gets executed so a delay of 3 sec worked here